# is it possible to reference a subdocument schema in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

is it possible to reference a sub document schema in mongoose ?

just like below

```
var sectionSchema = mongoose.Schema(
{
    id:{type:String,required:true},
    name:{type:String,required:true}
});
var courseSchema = mongoose.Schema(
{
    id:{type:String,required:true},
    name:{type:String,required:true},
    sections:[sectionSchema]
});
var studentSchema = mongoose.Schema(
{
    id:{type:String,required:true},
    name:{type:String,required:true},
    course:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'courseSchema'},
    section:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'sectionSchema'},
    contactnumber:{type:String,required:true},
    parentname:{type:String,required:true}
});
var schoolSchema = mongoose.Schema(
{
    id:{type:String,required:true},
    name:{type:String,required:true,unique:true},
    address:{type:String,required:true},
    year:{type:String,required:true},
    contactnumber:{type:String,required:true},
    courses:[courseSchema],
    students:[studentSchema]
});

var School = mongoose.model('School',schoolSchema);
```

in the above model i have section inside course which is inside school document.
i have students schema which is inside school document i want course to point to course schema and section to point to section schema.so is it possible to refer a sub document schema in mongoose.

Comment: If I am reading your intent correctly then you only want a single "School" model with various embedded schemata. But you are asking can items in those embedded schemata reference other embedded items. So it's not really clear what your point is. a "ref" in mongoose is used for "population" or pulling items from other collections. Since everything is embedded, then could you not just use  the basic `ObjectId`? Or possibly reference the data instead of embedding? This possibly leads to large documents otherwise.

Comment: what you said is exactly right.i know that ref is used to pull or populate te items from some other collection.in my case if i just use the type as object Id wit out using 'ref' then how do i pull the data from the refereed sub document ?